# Using exp4j mathematical expression evaluater

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator app for Android, which can also have scientific input, with trigonometric functions, factorial and so on. User can also input parentheses.

I'm using the exp4j library. However, there is not much documentation about it.

To those who have used exp4j or know something about it, will exp4j be able to evaluate such thing as empty functions, which should be skipped (Sin()) or user input errors such as 2.3.4 (multiple decimal dots)? Thank you very much.

Comment: asking for libs is normally off-topic...

Comment: Please note that this is not asking that. This question is targeted to someone who knows exp4j and asking whether it will be able to correctly evaluate for example 22.3.4 (instead of 22.34) and empty functions such as Sin().

Answer (score 0):

EXP4J will throw an `IllegalArgumentException()` if there are errors in input, as it should. It will be up to you to catch them and & inform the user on what he did wrong. Usually there are only syntax or math errors to be dealt with.

The limitation is that EXP4J will not be able to pinpoint where the specific errors in the input are, but you can easily deal with this by splitting the input and run it through EXP4J until it throws an exception again. This is usually necessary.